# How to avoid ok/cancel button in ion-option/ion-select

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng-options

Hi how to avoid the ok and cancel button in ion-options?

I need an output as the below image after clicking the ion-option. [image]

I have tried all the options as per http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/.

Yet I am not able to achieve this ui.

Even after typing `interface="action-sheet"` I am not able to achieve the wanted look.

Where can I find a demo or any help to get this view?

Comment: can you share your code sample

Comment: Did you see this? "If the number of options exceed 6, it will use the alert interface even if action-sheet is passed."

Comment: @Serg Chernata if I use action sheet I will not get the above look because action sheet will come under the bottom of the page but if look at the image I have posted it is not like that

Comment: @Ravin Singh D if you look at ion-select tag in official documents that will be an example because I am currently using that only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question was actually something I myself needed and I know some people have needed it for a while. So I hope this helps..

**OPTION 1: WRAPPED SUPER COMPONENT**

First we are creating a component called select-alertless.
Here is the HTML that has the options:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="model" #select>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let option options" [value]="option.id">{{option.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Really simple with a link for a view child.

Now the scss to hide the ok/cancel buttons:

```
.select-alertless{
    .alert-button-group{
        display:none;
        }
    }
```

The actual component class which looks for sets on the select inside the html. Looks for the options and sets an emit on the clicks. Thus everytime someone clicks one of the options it.
The open function is just here to dismiss the alert after you click.

```
 @Component({
    templateUrl: 'select-alertless.html',
    selector: 'select-alertless',
})
export class select_alertless {
    // the options that are displayed
    @Input('options') public options: any[];
    @Input('model') public model: any;

    // the event that is to be emitted when changes occures
    @Output('change') public change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    // The sets here capture events and emit the data to change when its needed. It also switched the open function for our own open function so then the viewcontroller can be closed.
    @ViewChild('select') public set ex(select: any | undefined) {
        if (select === undefined) return;
        select.open = this.open;
        if (select._options === undefined) {
            Object.defineProperty(select, '_options', {
                set: (val) => {
                    select['__options'] = val;
                    val.forEach(option => option.ionSelect.subscribe(d => {
                        this.change.emit(d);
                        this.model = d;

                        select.overlay.dismiss();
                    }));
                },
                get: function () { return select['__options'] }
            })
        }
    }
    open() {
        if ((<any>this)._disabled) {
            return;
        }

        console.debug('select, open alert');

        // the user may have assigned some options specifically for the alert
        const selectOptions = deepCopy((<any>this).selectOptions);

        // make sure their buttons array is removed from the options
        // and we create a new array for the alert's two buttons
        selectOptions.buttons = [{
            text: (<any>this).cancelText,
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
                (<any>this).ionCancel.emit(null);
            }
        }];

        // if the selectOptions didn't provide a title then use the label's text
        if (!selectOptions.title && (<any>this)._item) {
            selectOptions.title = (<any>this)._item.getLabelText();
        }

        let options = (<any>this)._options.toArray();


        // default to use the alert interface
        (<any>this).interface = 'alert';

        // user cannot provide inputs from selectOptions
        // alert inputs must be created by ionic from ion-options
        selectOptions.inputs = (<any>this)._options.map(input => {
            return {
                type: ((<any>this)._multi ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'),
                label: input.text,
                value: input.value,
                checked: input.selected,
                disabled: input.disabled,
                handler: (selectedOption: any) => {
                    // Only emit the select event if it is being checked
                    // For multi selects this won't emit when unchecking
                    if (selectedOption.checked) {
                        input.ionSelect.emit(input.value);
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        var selectCssClass = 'select-alert';

        // create the alert instance from our built up selectOptions
        (<any>this).overlay = new Alert((<any>(<any>this))._app, selectOptions);

        if ((<any>this)._multi) {
            // use checkboxes
            selectCssClass += ' multiple-select-alert select-alertless';
        } else {
            // use radio buttons
            selectCssClass += ' single-select-alert select-alertless';
        }

        // If the user passed a cssClass for the select, add it
        selectCssClass += selectOptions.cssClass ? ' ' + selectOptions.cssClass : '';
        (<any>this).overlay.setCssClass(selectCssClass);

        (<any>this).overlay.addButton({
            text: (<any>this).okText,
            handler: (selectedValues: any) => {
                (<any>this).onChange(selectedValues);
                (<any>this).ionChange.emit(selectedValues);
            }
        });


        (<any>this).overlay.present(selectOptions);

        (<any>this)._isOpen = true;
        (<any>this).overlay.onDidDismiss(() => {
            (<any>this)._isOpen = false;
        });
    }
}
```

This answer would've been a lot shorter if the created alert in select was public rather than a local variable.

Add this to your app module and you are free to use it.
Here is an example:

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label>stuff</ion-label>
            <select-alertless [model]="data" item-content [options]="options" (change)="data = $event"></select-alertless>
</ion-item>
```

You can add more inputs that are passed to the ion-select to have more configuration.

**OPTION 2: EXTEND SELECT ITSELF**

This would be a better solution since it gives you the option to just write the component like ion-select only select-alertless

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ContentChildren, ElementRef, EventEmitter, forwardRef, Input, HostListener, OnDestroy, Optional, Output, Renderer, QueryList, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

import { ActionSheet, Alert, App, Config, Form, Ion, Item, NavController, Option, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { isBlank, isCheckedProperty, isTrueProperty, deepCopy } from 'ionic-angular/util/util';
import { Select as ImportSelect } from 'ionic-angular/components/select/select';


export class TempSelect extends ImportSelect {
    static decorators = undefined;
    // static propDecorators = undefined;
}

export const SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => Select),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'select-alertless',
    styles: ['.select-alertless .alert-button-group{display:none}'],
    template:
'<div *ngIf="!_text" class="select-placeholder select-text">{{placeholder}}</div>' +
'<div *ngIf="_text" class="select-text">{{selectedText || _text}}</div>' +
'<div class="select-icon">' +
'<div class="select-icon-inner"></div>' +
'</div>' +
'<button aria-haspopup="true" ' +
'[id]="id" ' +
'ion-button="item-cover" ' +
'[attr.aria-labelledby]="_labelId" ' +
'[attr.aria-disabled]="_disabled" ' +
'class="item-cover">' +
'</button>',
host: {
        '[class.select-disabled]': '_disabled'
    },
    providers: [SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Select extends TempSelect implements AfterContentInit, ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
    public overlay: Alert;
    private __options: any;
    constructor(
        _app: App,
        _form: Form,
        config: Config,
        elementRef: ElementRef,
        renderer: Renderer,
        @Optional() public _item: Item,
        @Optional() _nav: NavController
    ) {
        super(_app, _form, config, elementRef, renderer, _item, _nav);
        this.setElementClass(`${this._componentName}-${this._mode}`, false);
    }
public set _options(val) {
    this.__options = val;
    if (!this._multi) {
        this.__options.forEach(option => {
            option.ionSelect.subscribe(selectedValues => {
                this.onChange(selectedValues);
                this.ionChange.emit(selectedValues);
                this._isOpen = false;
                this.overlay.dismiss();
            });
        });
    }
}
public get _options() {
    return this.__options;
}
open() {
    if (this._disabled) {
        return;
    }

    // the user may have assigned some options specifically for the alert
    const selectOptions = deepCopy(this.selectOptions);

    // make sure their buttons array is removed from the options
    // and we create a new array for the alert's two buttons
    selectOptions.buttons = [{
        text: this.cancelText,
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
            this.ionCancel.emit(null);
        }
    }];

    // if the selectOptions didn't provide a title then use the label's text
    if (!selectOptions.title && this._item) {
        selectOptions.title = this._item.getLabelText();
    }

    let options = this._options.toArray();


    // default to use the alert interface
    this.interface = 'alert';

    // user cannot provide inputs from selectOptions
    // alert inputs must be created by ionic from ion-options
    selectOptions.inputs = this._options.map(input => {
        return {
            type: (this._multi ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'),
            label: input.text,
            value: input.value,
            checked: input.selected,
            disabled: input.disabled,
            handler: (selectedOption: any) => {
                // Only emit the select event if it is being checked
                // For multi selects this won't emit when unchecking
                if (selectedOption.checked) {
                    input.ionSelect.emit(input.value);
                }
            }
        };
    });

    var selectCssClass = 'select-alert';

    // create the alert instance from our built up selectOptions
    this.overlay = new Alert((<any>this)._app, selectOptions);

    if (this._multi) {
        // use checkboxes
        selectCssClass += ' multiple-select-alert';
    } else {
        // use radio buttons
        selectCssClass += ' single-select-alert select-alertless';
    }

    // If the user passed a cssClass for the select, add it
    selectCssClass += selectOptions.cssClass ? ' ' + selectOptions.cssClass : '';
    this.overlay.setCssClass(selectCssClass);

    this.overlay.addButton({
        text: this.okText,
        handler: (selectedValues: any) => {
            this.onChange(selectedValues);
            this.ionChange.emit(selectedValues);
        }
    });


    this.overlay.present(selectOptions);

    this._isOpen = true;
    this.overlay.onDidDismiss(() => {
        this._isOpen = false;
    });
}
```

}

Use like:

```
<select-alertless item-content  [(ngModel)]="data"><ion-option></ion-option></select-alertless>
```

Basically use like normal select

For more information and an example project on how to use it consult this github:
https://github.com/misha130/ionic2-select-nobuttons

Comment: are you saying we have to make this as a custom component if possible can you provide an working plunker

Comment: i have just given the ion-select tag and inside my app.css file i have add the `.select-alertless{
    .alert-button-group{
        display:none;
        }
    }` thanks a lot i am able to avoid ok and cancel button but now i am not able to invoke the function on clicking the ion-option i have to invoke a function is it possible to do without custom tag

Comment: You can't. Gotta extend the open function in select so when you click an option it closes the select. Otherwise you just click between the options and it keeps displaying.

Comment: yes i am getting like that only but i want to invoke the function and then i can close the options list this is how i need to happened

Comment: You can't close the select if you don't have the ok/cancel buttons UNLESS you extend it. There is no function for it

Comment: actually i am not able to set array of ion-select because i am having the json object is like that so i am forced to use the click funtion inside the ion-select like`ionChance` or ionCancel` funtion provided by the doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: if some how if i mange to write the click function on the ion-options insted of ion-select then we can have some idea about that issue

Comment: Look at the viewchild in my code it. It attaches an event to each ion option and emits it when clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135550/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-misha130).

Comment: Come to chat so that we can disscuss

Comment: Its literally 7am I have to make breakfast and such. Ill be available in a few hours

Comment: no problem i will wait in chat once you are free please come to discussion

Comment: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in (new Alert((<any>(<any>this))._app, selectOptions);). Can you help, using ionic 3 and angular 4

Comment: Checked github?

Comment: Just now cloned it and it runs good in ionic 2, but i changed the package.json to the latest one. and it wasn't working. actually the Alert() has three parameters, but only two was supplied.

Comment: I changed your package to [this](http://i65.tinypic.com/2ccmsk3.png). Please take a look at it.

Comment: I updated it just now: https://github.com/misha130/ionic2-select-nobuttons/blob/master/src/pages/select/selectalertless.ts I didnt clone but I copy pasted from one of my currently working projects

Comment: this.setElementClass(`${this.componentName}`, false); in this line setElementClass and componentName does not exist!

Comment: I just declared it as 'any'. and also, having an issue in super(), it says 'super can only be referenced in a derived class'

Comment: oh remove the super. Its from my code.I'll clone and update again.

Comment: Thanks, Please let me know when you updated your code.