# Ionic 2/3/4 AlertController radio (ionChange) event handling

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

Good evening everyone. Wanted to ask you if there's a handler for the ionic alert radio buttons that handles the check by itself , but not buttons with handlers. Let's say I'm checking a radio and after that I'd like to execute any callback, but not on buttons click. Is there a way to succeed doing that? Been digging in github last hour but found nothing..

```
import { AllertController } from 'ionic-angular';

...
constructor( public alertController : AlertController ) {}
...

let alertController = this.alertController.create({
  title: `Title`,
  inputs: [
    {
     type: 'radio',
     label: 'Testlabel',
     value: 'Testvalue'
    },
    {
     type: 'radio',
     label: 'Testlabel',
     value: 'Testvalue'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
   { text: 'Cancel' },
   { text: 'Save' , handler: (data: any) => { // Want to execute that code 
     on input check , rather than on click on 'Save' button } }
  ]
});

alertController.present();
```

**If** there is no any solution related to `Alert Controller module` , I will be glad to receive any **custom** solutions , that can reproduce AlertController functionality and styles (**Something else rather than ModalController + ViewController**) or at least will be glad to know how to represent `ModalController` container with the same styles and behaviour like AlertController

Thanks and have a good evening to everyone!!!!

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7819#issuecomment-291893450). There is a feature request for this, but the comment linked provides a workaround.

Comment: A select without buttons that I wrote eons ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925172/how-to-avoid-ok-cancel-button-in-ion-option-ion-select/42193005#42193005

Answer (score 1):

AlertController inputs are of type `AlertInput` (see ionic 4 [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#inputs))

Digging into ionic github repository I found `AlertInput` [interface definition](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/alert/alert-interface.ts) which is supposed to take an `handler`.

```js
export interface AlertInput {
  type?: TextFieldTypes | 'checkbox' | 'radio';
  name?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  value?: any;
  label?: string;
  checked?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  id?: string;
  handler?: (input: AlertInput) => void; // here it is!
  min?: string | number;
  max?: string | number;
}
```

This handler works with 'radio' and 'checkbox' input type, and doesn't seem to be implemented with 'text' input type.

Here is an example:

```js
async presentAlertConfirm() {
  const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header: 'Confirm!',
    message: 'Message <strong>text</strong>!!!',
    inputs: [
      {
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'Testlabel',
        value: 'radiovalue',
        placeholder: 'Placeholder 1',
        handler: (input) =>  {
          console.log(input.value); // will contain 'radiovalue'
        },
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        cssClass: 'secondary',
        handler: (blah) => {
          console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Okay',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Confirm Okay');
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  await alert.present();
}
```

In you component template html file:

```html
<ion-button (click)="presentAlertConfirm()">Alert!</ion-button>
```